# How to use instrumentation with Unity build?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to run instrumentation profiler on my Unity build to know which functions are called the most and take the most time.

I have created librairies in C# which are imported in Unity, I can debug them without problems but am not able to start the visual studio profiler to instrument them.

I couldn't find an instrumentation function in Unity. Or at least it seems to crash and I get many exceptions after a few minutes of running. (ThreadDeserializer should not parse more data once it has been marked as terminated)

I have tried:

- attach VS to Unity play mode but the instrumentation option isn't active
- build in Unity with Debug options, PDB copied, deep profiling enabled, when trying to profile the .exe from Visual Studio I get

> Unable to obtain debugging information.
> PRF0002: The instrumentation with those options has failed

- I also try to run my application .exe and attach VS's debugger but the instrumentation option is available.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you already tried the built in profiler?

Comment: I'm not sure if we're both missing something (hence a comment and not an answer), but Unity's documentation page called "Profiling and debugging with Unity and native platform tools" has no mention of "Visual Studio profiler".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not satisfied at all with the profiler from Unity, I find it very bugged and much harder to use for a whole session (I don't really want to see all the data live or at a given time, just the instrumentation of the whole execution). And I know how good the VS profiling tools are so if there is a way to use them I'd like to!